# Why is my this.class always undefined with jQuery filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to get all the div elements with classes having a name containing print. I am trying to achieve this like so:

```
const matchedContainer = [];
    $('div').filter(() => {
        regex = new RegExp("\w*print\w*","i");
        if( this.class !== undefined && this.class.match(regex)) {
            var elementContents = $(this).prop('outerHTML'); 
            matchedContainer.push(elementContents);
        }
    }
```

Here I am never able to enter the if loop as this.class is always equated to undefined. I also tried with ".each" instead of ".filter" with the same result. I also tried giving names to each element by ".filter((ind,elem)=>{...})" and then tried using elem.class but that didn't work as well.

I tried a similar approach with this.id and that worked fine, can anyone tell me as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

> Here I am never able to enter the if loop as this.class is always
>   equated to undefined

You are accessing a property of an object which does't exists.

An Element doesn't have a class **property** (*not attribute*), it has a [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property.

Use `this.className` instead of `this.class`.

**Edit**

since you are using an arrow function, `this` refers to the enclosing scope. Make it

```
$('div').filter((i, v) => { //i and v are index and value
    regex = new RegExp("\w*print\w*","i");
    if( v.className !== undefined && v.className.match(regex)) { //use v instead of this
        var elementContents = $(this).prop('outerHTML'); 
        matchedContainer.push(elementContents);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` gives reference to the `Window` object. How can you say this is write answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code:

1. The `this` inside the `filter` gives you the reference of `Window` object and not `div` element
2. You should be using `className` instead of `class` in `this` only if `this` referenced the `div` element. But it does not reference the div element

```js
const matchedContainer = [];
$('div').filter((index, elem) => {
    regex = new RegExp("\w*print\w*","i");
    if( $(elem).attr('class') !== undefined && $(elem).attr('class').match(regex)) {
        var elementContents = $(elem).prop('outerHTML'); 
        matchedContainer.push(elementContents);
    }
});
console.log(matchedContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='print123'>1</div>
<div class='152print'>23</div>
<div class='print'>789</div>
<div class='pprint'>852</div>
```

Incorrect answer as suggested by **gurvinder** above:

```js
const matchedContainer = [];
$('div').filter(() => {
    regex = new RegExp("\w*print\w*","i");
    if( this.className !== undefined && this.className.match(regex)) {
        var elementContents = $(this).prop('outerHTML'); 
        matchedContainer.push(elementContents);
    }
});
console.log(matchedContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='print123'>1</div>
<div class='152print'>23</div>
<div class='print'>789</div>
<div class='pprint'>852</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use: `$('div[class*="print"]')`

If we are talking about 2 or 3 classes you can use `$(".class1,.class2,.class3,...")`

If the class name is on the beginning of the string you can use `$("div[class^='print-']")`